# Rotating Testimonial

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

I'd appreciate some help in fixing this little testimonial box of mine. Now, I don't know if the problem is the PHP, CSS, or just my markup, because the although the posts seem to fade, they all appear at once and the first fade just goes on to show the third post.

Here's the script:

```
    <script language="javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#testimonials .slide');
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery('#testimonials .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            if(jQuery(this).next('.slide').size()){
                jQuery(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
            }
            else{
                jQuery('#testimonials .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    },1500);    
}); 
</script>
```

PHP/HTML:

```
<?php 
  $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'qcamp', 'posts_per_page' => 5)); 
  if ($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
<div id="camps-quote">

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <div id="testimonials">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="testimonial-quote">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>  

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and finally the CSS:

```
#camps-quote {
    margin-top:50px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px #C0C0C0; 
    background-color: #7D9EC0; 
    height: 120px; 
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:7px;
    font-family: Arial;
    width:500px;
    margin-left:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#testimonials{

}

#testimonials .slide {color: #fff;}

#testimonials .testimonial-quote {
    padding: 3px 0 0 65px; 
    line-height: 1.5em; 
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: italic; 
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
```

[Here's the site I'm testing it on.](http://www.botkai.com/camps-page/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things - (1) remove the `<div id="testimonials">` from within the loop. And (2) set all but the first `<div class="slide">` to `style="display:none"` on page load. You can do this by setting up a basic counter (ie. `$i=0; $i++;`)

```
<?php 
  $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'qcamp', 'posts_per_page' => 5)); 
  if ($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
<div id="camps-quote">
<div id="testimonials">
<?php $i=0; // set up a basic counter counter ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="slide" <?php if ($i > 0) echo 'style="display:none"'; ?> >
            <div class="testimonial-quote">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php $i++; // increase the counter ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>  

</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Check out the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CEqKu/

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to follow a tutorial, but this part was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

One problem in the php / markup / javascript is that `#testimonials` is inside the loop. It should be out of the loop as now your `.slide` elements have no siblings and `next()` gets the next sibling (and you can only have one unique ID per page; now you have as many `#testimonials` elements as you have testimonials):

```
<div id="testimonials">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="testimonial-quote">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Right, but even so, all three posts appear all at once. I'd like them to "slide."

Comment: @Brian Right now you are not doing any sliding, just fading. You could replace that with `slideUp` and `slideDown` but if you want continues movement (sliding up and in view from below), you would have to change a lot (using a window / box with overflow hidden, absolutely positioned elements and animations from below the box to above the box).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Let me clear that I up. I want the posts to fade in/out one at a time. Currently they all appear at the same time and all fade in/out simultaneously.

Comment: @Brian I normally add a class to the currently visible element and remove that and set it to the next (or the first if there is no next) on animation.